# Explanation of capabilities: CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE

Tags: linux, permissions, credentials, kernel, capabilities

I am still studying kernel credential management (https://kernel.org/doc/html/v5.9/security/credentials.html) and I have encountered a use case I cannot explain.

- I am in a VM (Kali).

```
❯ uname -a
Linux cactus-ths 5.18.0-kali5-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 5.18.5-1kali6 (2022-07-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

- My UID is not 0:

````
❯ id
uid=1000(seb) gid=1000(seb) groupes=1000(seb),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),25(floppy),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),109(netdev),113(bluetooth),120(scanner),138(wireshark),141(kaboxer)```
````

- Current capabilities of the calling process:

```
❯ capsh --print
Current: =
Bounding set =cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_linux_immutable,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_broadcast,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_ipc_lock,cap_ipc_owner,cap_sys_module,cap_sys_rawio,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_sys_pacct,cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_boot,cap_sys_nice,cap_sys_resource,cap_sys_time,cap_sys_tty_config,cap_mknod,cap_lease,cap_audit_write,cap_audit_control,cap_setfcap,cap_mac_override,cap_mac_admin,cap_syslog,cap_wake_alarm,cap_block_suspend,cap_audit_read,cap_perfmon,cap_bpf,cap_checkpoint_restore
Ambient set =
Current IAB: 
Securebits: 00/0x0/1'b0
 secure-noroot: no (unlocked)
 secure-no-suid-fixup: no (unlocked)
 secure-keep-caps: no (unlocked)
 secure-no-ambient-raise: no (unlocked)
uid=1000(seb) euid=1000(seb)
gid=1000(seb)
groups=4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),25(floppy),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),109(netdev),113(bluetooth),120(scanner),138(wireshark),141(kaboxer),1000(seb)
Guessed mode: UNCERTAIN (0)

❯ cat /proc/self/status | grep Cap
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
CapBnd: 000001ffffffffff
CapAmb: 0000000000000000
```

- File capabilities of `nc` (nothing):

```
❯ getcap /bin/nc.traditional
```

- File permissions of `nc`:

```
❯ ls -la /bin/nc.traditional 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 34952 20 août   2021 /bin/nc.traditional
```

**Why I can launch `nc` to listen on TCP/80 ?**

```
❯ /bin/nc.traditional -nvlp 80
listening on [any] 80 ...
```

*Capabilities of the launched process:*

```
❯ cat /proc/15669/status | grep Cap
CapInh: 0000000000000000
CapPrm: 0000000000000000
CapEff: 0000000000000000
CapBnd: 000001ffffffffff
CapAmb: 0000000000000000
```

*strace*

```
❯ strace /bin/nc.traditional -nvlp 80
execve("/bin/nc.traditional", ["/bin/nc.traditional", "-nvlp", "80"], 0x7fffd61f2890 /* 80 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55fc48da1000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f027c974000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=101666, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 101666, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f027c95b000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\300\223\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\20\0\0\0\5\0\0\0GNU\0\2\200\0\300\4\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32, 848) = 32
pread64(3, "\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\244\311\214\f|x\0031\37\275\221\215\370\373\10\333"..., 68, 880) = 68
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2049032, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
pread64(3, "\6\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 784, 64) = 784
mmap(NULL, 2101136, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f027c600000
mmap(0x7f027c628000, 1499136, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x28000) = 0x7f027c628000
mmap(0x7f027c796000, 360448, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x196000) = 0x7f027c796000
mmap(0x7f027c7ee000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1ed000) = 0x7f027c7ee000
mmap(0x7f027c7f4000, 53136, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f027c7f4000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f027c958000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f027c958740) = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f027c958a10)         = 17783
set_robust_list(0x7f027c958a20, 24)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f027c7ee000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x55fc482d2000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f027c9a6000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
munmap(0x7f027c95b000, 101666)          = 0
getpid()                                = 17783
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/resolv.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=46, ...}, 0) = 0
getrandom("\xca\xb5\xfa\x74\x1c\x77\x14\xa0", 8, GRND_NONBLOCK) = 8
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55fc48da1000
brk(0x55fc48dc2000)                     = 0x55fc48dc2000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/host.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
read(3, "multi on\n", 4096)             = 9
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
futex(0x7f027c7fb46c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=46, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
read(3, "nameserver 10.12.128.1\nnameserve"..., 4096) = 46
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="cactus-ths", ...}) = 0
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=46, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
getpid()                                = 17783
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x55fc482cd280, sa_mask=[INT], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f027c63daf0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=0x55fc482cd280, sa_mask=[QUIT], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f027c63daf0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, {sa_handler=0x55fc482cd280, sa_mask=[TERM], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f027c63daf0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGURG, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[URG], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f027c63daf0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[PIPE], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f027c63daf0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
close(3)                                = 0
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
close(3)                                = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/nsswitch.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=553, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=553, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
read(3, "# /etc/nsswitch.conf\n#\n# Example"..., 4096) = 553
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=553, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=101666, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
mmap(NULL, 101666, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f027c95b000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/x86_64", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/x86_64", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=155648, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/x86_64", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/x86_64", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=155648, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/x86_64/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/x86_64/x86_64", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/tls", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64/x86_64", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}, 0) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/glibc-hwcaps/x86-64-v2", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/x86_64", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/tls/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/tls", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64/x86_64", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64", 0x7ffd8c90d800, 0) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/libnss_db.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}, 0) = 0
munmap(0x7f027c95b000, 101666)          = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/services", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=12813, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
read(3, "# Network services, Internet sty"..., 4096) = 4096
close(3)                                = 0
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) = 3
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, [1], 4) = 0
setsockopt(3, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, [1], 4) = 0
bind(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(80), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = 0
listen(3, 1)                            = 0
getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(80), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, [16]) = 0
write(2, "listening on [any] 80 ...", 25listening on [any] 80 ...) = 25
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[ALRM], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f027c63daf0}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
alarm(0)                                = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
accept(3,
```

Normally, I should need CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE in CapEff of the calling process or need this capability on the file right ?

Is it a misconfiguration of my system ?

Can you help me to analyze the situation ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

Ok I understood ... Maybe it will help someone who encounters the same situation.

Privileged ports numbers are registered at system level, but configurable.

In my case, all TCP ports were unprivileged:

```
❯ sudo sysctl -a | grep "net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start"
net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start = 0
```

So CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE is totally useless here :)